# vectorize and parallelize if it's add compute?

Tags: python, multithreading, vectorization

What's the most efficient technique and Why?

```
min_dist = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
    for i in range(len(self.data)):
        data = self.data[i]
        dist = MySuperLongFunction(data)
        if dist < min_dist:
            min_dist = dist
    return min_dist
```

or

```
vdist = [0]*len(self.data)
    for i in range(len(self.data)):
        data = self.data[i]
        dist = MySuperLongFunction(data)
        vdist[i] = dist
 return min(vdist)
```

I know that the min(vdist) add compute to do but the second one can be parallelize verry easily because the for don't depend of previous itération so I can compute 8 time at one the MySuperLongFunction(data). So what's the most effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the function value for each input data in self.data, hence, `DARRAY = [MySuperLongFunction(x) for x in self.data]` has to be computed no matter what.
As you already pointed out, computing `DARRAY` could be parallelized, hence, we are left with returning the `min` value in this case,

So, i would say it's `min([MySuperLongFunction(x) for x in self.data])`